# Bolt cms ckeditor image upload

Tags: ckeditor, bolt-cms

I am trying to upload images from ckeditor.

The option in config, only allows you to add images from the stack.

In docs I did not find anything related to uploading images. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 7):

In your `app/config/config.yml` file you will find the following set of options:

```
wysiwyg:
    images: false            # Allow users to insert images in the content.
    anchor: false            # Adds a button to create internal anchors to link to.
    tables: false            # Adds a button to insert and modify tables in the content.
    fontcolor: false         # Allow users to mess around with font coloring.
    align: false             # Adds buttons for 'align left', 'align right', etc.
    subsuper: false          # Adds buttons for subscript and superscript, using `<sub>` and `<sup>`.
    embed: false             # Allows the user to insert embedded video's from Youtube, Vimeo, etc.
    underline: false         # Adds a button to underline text, using the `<u>`-tag.
    ruler: false             # Adds a button to add a horizontal ruler, using the `<hr>`-tag.
    strike: false            # Adds a button to add stikethrough, using the `<s>`-tag.
    blockquote: false        # Allows the user to insert code snippets using `<pre><code>`-tags.
    codesnippet: false       # Allows the user to insert blockquotes using the `<blockquote>`-tag.
    specialchar: false       # Adds a button to insert special chars like '€' or '™'.
```

You just want to set `images: true` and that will tell CKeditor to enable the image plugin.

Comment: That enables loading images from the stack on CKeditor. I want to be able to also upload images, not only select them from stack.

Comment: The stack or the `files/` directory.

Comment: If you want to upload a set of images, that can be managed via `File Management -> Uploaded Files`

Comment: Any cms has the ability to upload images right on the editor. I don`t find it appropriate to go on other page to upload the image and then come back here to select it.